# Form submit with javascript works in Google Chrome only once

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, submit

I have simple form.

```
<form target="_blank" action="somescript.php" method="Post" id="simpleForm">
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://...">
<input type="hidden" name="code" value="wrxosf">
</form>
```

...and there are some anchor link

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('#simpleForm').submit();return false;">Do it!</a>
```

It works fine in FireFox or IE, but Google Chrome.
Chrome does once, then link become unclickable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Forms with **target="_blank"** submiting only once.
This is [webkit](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=28633) & [chromium](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=16528) bugs.

Comment: Same thing happens with target="SomethingElse".  (Ilya's solution works for that case as well.)

Answer (score 7):

Also had such problem.

The decision was to add something random to URL each time before submitting.

HTML:

```
<form action="go.php" method="post" target="_blank" id="go">
...
</form>
```

JavaScript (jQuery):

```
$('#go').attr('action','go.php?'+Math.random()*1000).submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

I am running Chrome 7.0.5 and also still having this problem.  Setting the action to something different each time as suggested above works! :)

Answer (score 0):

This problem was fixed in the latest version of `Chrome 5.0.375.55`